# Uninstalling Ubuntu Installed Alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall

I want to Uninstall Ubuntu installed alongside of Windows 10 on same drive i.e. on drive C. Since due to dual boot my windows files are getting corrupted. Please help me to get out from this.

Comment: If your Windows files are being corrupted, then seems you have made some unwise choices when installing Ubuntu. Use your Windows Restore feature to purge Ubuntu and reinstall Windows properly. This seems like a Windows support question, not an Ubuntu support question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that install is in UEFI, get Mini Tool Partition Wizard free trial. Launch it and delete Ubuntu partitions. Apply changes Then, resize C: drive to get an NTSF partition, apply changes. Don’t restart. Now, delete grub and rewrite the Windows EFI partition in Command Prompt Admin Mode. Run the following commands one-by-one:

1. mountvol U: /s
2. del /f /s /q U:*.*
3. bcdboot C:\Windows

Exit and Restart. Machine is set for another dual boot. Works when dual boot with MAC or Ten with Ten, removes volume 5 and boot screen. **Works only in UEFI mode.**

What is corrupted files, meaning? Backup important files first and get Ccleaner to clean the machine, especially the registry cleaner. Make sure to unchecked any third party app during installation.

Next time you dual boot, let the installer do the work = auto-resize slider. Ubuntu, when properly installed does not corrupt Win files.

https://www.minitool.com/partition-manager/

https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner/download